# ode with cross product

Tags: classical-mechanics

I am trying to find $\vec{r}(t)$ starting from $ \sum \vec{F} = m\vec{a} $ where $\vec{r}(t)$ is the flight of a cricket ball. The problem I have is that one of the forces ([Magnus effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect)) that acts on a cricket ball and causes it to drift works perpendicular to the spin axis and the direction of travel.

The formula I am using for this is: 
$$\vec{a}(t) =  \frac{16}3  \pi^2 c r^3  \rho  \omega  v \left\lVert \vec{u}(t) \times \vec{s} \right\rVert$$
Where $ \frac{16}3  \pi^2 c r^3  \rho  \omega  v$ are a whole bunch of constants (lift coefficient, radius, air pressure, spin, wind velocity respectively).

$\vec{u}(t)$ is the direction of motion, $\vec{s}$ is the spin axis (which is orthogonal to the seam of the cricket ball). The force operates at right angles to both of these vectors,

I am unsure how to integrate this in order to handle the cross product as obviously $\vec{r}(t)$ travels in its own direction. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

x posted from maths

Comment: The left hand side is a vector, and the right hand side is a scalar! Did you mean $\frac{d}{dt}\vec{u}=-k \vec{s}\times \vec{u}$, with $u$ the velocity vector of the ball? (NOT its direction unit vector) To solve this equation, write the ODEs for $u$ explicitly in an orthonormal coordinate system with, say, the $\hat{z}$ axis pointing in the direction of $\vec{s}$.

Comment: Crossposted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1970876/11127

Answer (score -1):

That's just the magnitude of the cross product on the right hand side, isn't it?

The magnitude of the cross product isn't a vector, it's a scalar. Do the cross product, compute the magnitude (yielding a scalar function with t-dependence on the RHS) and then integrate it.

Comment: I have no idea why this has been marked down^. The above notation is the standard modulus/magnitude notation. Unless it has been incorrectly notated, then the RHS is a t-dependent scalar.